# Is viewInstance.undelegateEvents() the same as $(this.el).unbind()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is `viewInstance.undelegateEvents()` the same as jQuery's `$(this.el).unbind()`?

Do they function the same way, as in removing the events from the view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-131

```
    undelegateEvents: function() {
      this.$el.unbind('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);
    },
```

So, they are nearly identical. But the `undelegateEvents` method scopes the undelegation to the events that the backbone view had explicitly set up with the `delegateEvents` method, using the declarative `events` configuration on the view.

Comment: thanks Derick, you're on a roll today! I love Backbone.js! Just wondering.. do you have a 'workflow' of when you develop Backbone-based apps? -- some kind of 'personal' architectural steps or so? Being that this is so flexible, I am not used to not being told exactly what to do like in Ember.js and etc..

Comment: I do: Backbone.Marionette. it's all wrapped up and available at https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette with a demo app at https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail it's not quite as prescriptive as Ember, but it's further down that path than raw backbone :)

Comment: hmm.. that's perfect. thanks a lot Derick :) will definitely check it out.

Comment: what if I wanted to undelegateEvents and after delegateEvents only for some specific events (not all as default). Is it possible to do?